# a tag seen twice on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iphone, ipad

I have created a tag which on click opens a simple popup asking for an email id to retrieve the password. Now, when I click on forget password it shows me the forget link two times. Below is my code.

```
<a href="#forgot_password" id="forgotPassword">Forgot Password?</a>
```

Given is code for JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#username").focus();
            $('a[href="#forgot_password"]').click(function () {
                if ($("#username").val().length > 0) {
                    try {
                        var retVal = "";
                        $("#errMsg").text('');
                        $("#errMsg").removeClass("error");
                        var urlCreate = "login.aspx?method=ForgotPasswordSecurityQuestion&userName=" + String($("#username").val());
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: urlCreate,
                            contentType: "text/plain",
                            dataType: "",
                            success: function (response) {
                                //alert(response);
                                if (String(response).length >= 0) {

                                    if (response.indexOf('not found') > 0) {
                                        ShowError(response);
                                    }
                                    else {

                                        var returnVal = response.split("|");
                                        var re = new RegExp('_', 'g');
                                        $('#securityQuestion').text((returnVal[1]).replace(re," ") + "?");

                                        securityAnswer = returnVal[2];
                                        userID = returnVal[0];
                                        ShowSplashScreen("splashScreenForgotPassword");
                                    }
                                }
                                else {

                                    ShowError("error occurred while processing your request");
                                }
                            },
                            error: function (response) {
                                ShowError(response);

                            }
                        });
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        alert("Catch" + err);
                    }

                }
                else {
                    ShowError("Please enter user name");
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your href and id both are conflicting and generating issue.
Please try with the below code.
HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="forgotPassword">Forgot Password?</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#username").focus();
        $('#forgotPassword').click(function () {
            // your code here
        });
});
```